# texView.setText("String"); does not keep new Text setted

Tags: java, android, xml, bluetooth, textview

I'm programming a code to open my room's door. But I have an issue. 
The TextView.setText does not keep the new String I can see the String changed when the system ask to the user if allow enable Bluetooth textViewBluetooth.setText works, but when the bluetooth is enabled the textViewBluetooth returns to the original String setted on activity_main.xml and I never see it update again even setting text on an special button.

I already debug my code, i can see the setText called in TextView but still have no update string.
I try to add a new TextView but I get the same issue in both TextView.
I comment the bluetoothThread class but the problem persist.

Thanks for your time.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private static final int RESULT_SETTINGS = 1;
private BluetoothAdapter mBTadapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice>pairedDevices;

private BluetoothThread mBluetoothThread = null;

final String deviceAddress = "98:D3:31:20:0B:C9";
String SN = null;

TextView textViewBluetooth;
ImageView imageViewBT;
ImageView imageViewAbrir;
ImageView imageViewCerrar;

boolean NewDevice = false;

ArrayList listNoBondedDevices = new ArrayList();
ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textViewBluetooth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView01);
    imageViewBT = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewBT);
    imageViewAbrir = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewAbrir);
    imageViewCerrar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewCerrar);

    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listNoBondedDevices);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver,new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));

    mBluetoothThread = new BluetoothThread();
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(mBTadapter.isEnabled()){
        if(!mBluetoothThread.btSocketConnected) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            tryConnectBTdevice(deviceAddress);
        }
    }
    else {
        intentEnableBT();
    }
}

void intentEnableBT(){
    textViewBluetooth.setText("Encendiendo bluetooth");
    Intent intentEnableBT = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intentEnableBT, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
}

void tryConnectBTdevice(String address){
    if(address != null && address != "00:00:00:00:00:00") {
        BluetoothDevice mBTdevice = mBTadapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        if (!mBluetoothThread.btSocketConnected) {
            textViewBluetooth.setText("Conectando a\n" + address.toString());
            mBluetoothThread.connect(mBTdevice);
        }
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    switch (requestCode){
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                textViewBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth encendido");
                tryConnectBTdevice(deviceAddress);
            }
            else if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
                textViewBluetooth.setText("No se logró encender Bluetooth");
            }
            break;
    }
}
}
```

My BluetoothThread:

```
public class BluetoothThread {
boolean bconnectedthread = false;
boolean bconnectthread = false;
boolean bconnectthreadstart = false;
boolean brun = false;
boolean bconnectedsynchronized = false;
boolean btSocketConnected = false;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
private static final UUID MY_UUID = 
UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
private ConnectThread mConnectThread;

public void write(byte[] out) {
    ConnectedThread r;
    synchronized (this) {

        r = mConnectedThread;
    }
    r.write(out);

}

private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;


    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;
        bconnectthread = true;
        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        brun=true;
        try {
            mmSocket.connect();
            btSocketConnected = true;
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
            return;
        }
        connected(mmSocket);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
            btSocketConnected = false;
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}


private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
    public Handler mHandler = null;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        bconnectedthread = true;
        Message message;
        Handler mHandler;

        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        while (true) {
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                //mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                //   .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public void disconnectDevice() {
        if (mmSocket.isConnected()) {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
                btSocketConnected = false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}

public synchronized void disconnect(){
    mConnectedThread.disconnectDevice();
}


public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device)

{
    bconnectthreadstart=true;
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
    mConnectThread.start();

}


public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket) {

    bconnectedsynchronized=true;
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
    mConnectedThread.start();

}
```

}

My activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.automovil.app.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewBT"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/bluetooth"
    android:onClick="onSyncBT" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textView01"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewBT"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:textColor="#00026a"
    android:text="Bluetooth"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:editable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:autoLink="none" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Sorry for my English grammar :\
Thanks a lot for your time again.
Abraham Jaime

Comment: Please post your code as an [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem. There's a lot of redundant code in your example that has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: I already edit the question, Thanks a lot Duncan

Comment: So the button is always just saying "Bluetooth"? Or does it change to something else sometimes? If so, when / what to?

Comment: Hi Alex Coleman, the TextView alwways has "Bluetooth" Text, i Only can see a diferent Text while Bluetooth is enabling.

Comment: I made this test:
`if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                    textViewBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth encendido");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),textViewBluetooth.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    tryConnectBTdevice(deviceAddress);}`

The Toast show "Bluetooth encendido" as the settext("Bluetooth encendido"); but the TextView still show the original text "Bluetooth"

Answer (score 0):

You're calling 'setContentView' in onResume.  Call that in onCreate.

onActivityResult is called BEFORE onResume, and you're doing your own multithreading here, which can be rough.  Especially in this case.

tryConnectBTdevice is called from onActivityResult, which then starts a thread, but 99% of the time you'll probably wind up in in onResume before all of that happens, which means your code calls setContentView again, AND tryConnectBTdevice again.

You're referencing boolean primitives from multiple threads to check for status, which isn't great.  Should probably use AtomicBoolean, but that's probably not a huge issue.

What would get a long talk from me if we were working together is eating your IOException's.  Error control is very important.  Those are being thrown for a reason.  Its probably blowing up because you're already connected, which would've tipped you off to the double-call situation.

Simple answer, assuming you're going to ignore all my warnings about exceptions.  Don't call setContentView in onResume, and don't call tryConnectBTdevice in onActivityResult, because you're calling it from onResume anyway.

If this is for *your* room, OK.  If you're making a product, I'd strongly advise a rewrite of the threading code.

Comment: Thanks for your advices. I solve it, in BluetoothThread i was calling mBluetoothThread.disconnect() but in BluetoothThread.java was not sincronized.

I called setContentView(main_activity) in onResume because when the BluetoothSocket is connected i change the layout but in resume i return to activity main to try connect again. But really I appreciate your time and advices

Comment: OK, but the reason why you're resetting the text view is because you're calling setContentView in onResume.  That's why.  You *should* make changes to your UI in a different manner, but that's a different discussion.  You are calling your connect method multiple times.  It may "work", but its not "solved".